# Appcenter build Failed Errno::EEXIST - File exists @ syserr_fail2_in

Tags: react-native, appcenter

I got this after a while.
While building `react-native` on `Appcenter`

```
### Error

Errno::EEXIST - File exists @ syserr_fail2_in - /Users/runner/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/hermes-engine/1093ead2a8c068cdef04abc8f93419c7-4438d/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/Resources
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.6_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:1390:in `symlink'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.6_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:1390:in `copy'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.6_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:500:in `block in copy_entry'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.6_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:1513:in `wrap_traverse'

....


――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=File+exists+%40+syserr_fail2_in+-+%2FUsers%2Frunner%2FLibrary%2FCaches%2FCocoaPods%2FPods%2FExternal%2Fhermes-engine%2F1093ead2a8c068cdef04abc8f93419c7-4438d%2Fdestroot%2FLibrary%2FFrameworks%2Funiversal%2Fhermes.xcframework%2Fios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst%2Fhermes.framework%2FResources&type=Issues
```

I am using these libs

```
  "appcenter": "4.4.5",
  "appcenter-analytics": "4.4.5",
  "appcenter-crashes": "4.4.5",
  "react-native": "0.71.7",
```

on appcenter logs

```
[!] Error installing hermes-engine

...

### Stack

   CocoaPods : 1.15.0
        Ruby : ruby 3.0.6p216 (2023-03-30 revision 23a532679b) [x86_64-darwin21]
    RubyGems : 3.5.5
        Host : macOS 12.7.3 (21H1015)
       Xcode : 14.2 (14C18)
         Git : git version 2.43.0
Ruby lib dir : /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.6_1/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood a new version cocoapods is broken.
Here's what helped me.
U need to implement appcenter-post-clone.sh script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "uninstalling all cocoapods versions"
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods --all
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.14.3
```

and in gemfile in your project set version for cocoapods:

```
gem 'cocoapods', '>= 1.13', '< 1.15'
```

Comment: This worked on my side. :)
Thanks you.


I just tweak something
`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods --all --force`

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods 1.15.2 (released on 6th Feb 2024) supposedly fixed this issue.